# Оператор приведения типа для объектных типов

Tags: objective-c

Есть два

```
NSNumber *floatNumber
```

содержащие дробные значения.
Каким образом привести значения этих объектов к целочисленным(оставить значение просто отбросив дробную часть) и каким образом их потом сравнить уже как целочисленные (то есть не приводя их к примитивным типам а оставив объектными) ? Для сравнения использовать  метод isEqualToNumber или что-то иное?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для возвращения целочисленного значения используйте `[floatNumber intValue]` либо `[floatNumber integerValue]`

В первом случае возвращается тип `int`, во втором же - `NSInteger`.

PS Да, для сравнения лучше использовать `isEqualToNumber`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!